# clipsToBounds in React Native

Tags: react-native

What is an alternative to `clipsToBounds = true` in React Native? I have subviews going beyond the bounds of a parent view. In iOS using swift, I would solve it with `clipsToBounds = true`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have to use the `style` property of your view and set `overflow` to `hidden`. Something like this:

```
<View style={{ overflow: ‘hidden’ }}>
   {/* These views won’t be presented out of the view */}
</View>
```

Comment: Also note that `overflow: hidden` will hide the shadows if you set any.